# Why sending data by Ajax jQuery fail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create a pop-up form login with Ajax jQuery, but It's always fail to send data. I've many ways on Internet that I can find but nothing change. Please take a look and help me. Thanks so much:
This is my form:

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class='modal-body-left' >
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Tên đăng nhập" value="" class="form-control login-field">
            <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Mật khẩu" value="" class="form-control login-field">
            <i class="fa fa-lock login-field-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top: -8px"> Nhớ mật khẩu
            </label>
            <a href="#" style="float: right;">Quên mật khẩu?</a>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success modal-login-btn" id="loginbutton" name="loginbutton"  style="background-color: #47a49a; background: #fec10f;" type="submit">Đăng nhập</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my js:

```
$("#loginbutton").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var data ={"email":username, "password":password};
    alert(data.email);
    // alert(data.password);
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '{{url('/')}}/loginHandling',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'email': "ruoitrau95@gmail.com", 'password':"tuyen12345"},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                alert("done");
            }   
        }
    )
    .fail(function(data) {
        alert("fail");
    }); 
});
```

And this is controller:

```
public function loginHandling() {

    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    $check $this->pages->checkLogin($email, $password);
    echo "alert(In loginHandling)";
    if ($check) {
        $name = $this->pages->getNameFromMail($email);
        Session::put('logined', true);
        Session::put('email', $email);
        Session::put('name', $name);

        die json_encode(array("success"=>"true"));
    } else {
        die json_encode(array("success"=>"false"));
    }

}
```

I'm working on Laravel framework so my url is defined:

```
Route::post('/loginHandling',['as'=>'loginHandling','uses'=>'LoginController@loginHandling']);
```

Thanks again for your time

Comment: In what way specifically does this fail?  When you debug this, when does an actual problem happen?  What are the relevant values when that happens?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know. When I try to find problem by sending message in Postman, I get this `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68` but I don't know what it is. I think data can't be send to controller, because I try some test code on controller, but it didn't work

Comment: **1.**  `{{ csrf_field() }}` generates `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="value">` , so you have to pass `_token` in data in $.ajax method.  **2.** you can set request header in jquery `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});` and you have to add `<meta name='csrf-token' content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your app.blade.php file

Comment: It seem you have the same answer with @jackel414 but it's still fail. Any reason for this? configuration and something else? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the CSRF token in order for Laravel to process the request. There are a few ways to do this - try this one:

Form:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />            
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST">
    <div class='modal-body-left' >
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Tên đăng nhập" value="" class="form-control login-field">
            <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Mật khẩu" value="" class="form-control login-field">
            <i class="fa fa-lock login-field-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top: -8px"> Nhớ mật khẩu
            </label>
            <a href="#" style="float: right;">Quên mật khẩu?</a>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success modal-login-btn" id="loginbutton" name="loginbutton"  style="background-color: #47a49a; background: #fec10f;" type="submit">Đăng nhập</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#loginbutton").click(function(event) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '{{url('/')}}/loginHandling',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'email': username, 'password': password},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                alert("done");
            }   
        }
    )
    .fail(function(data) {
        alert("fail");
    }); 
});
```

You should now be able to access the submitted data in your controller with `$request->all()`.

Comment: Thanks for yout time, but it is still fail. Any reason for this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I left off the name of the header. It should be headers: `{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}`. I updated my answer. That should do the trick.

Comment: It still does not work, i think there are something more than that, I don't know if it relates with this form and function. I'm very confused now. I'm a newbie and can't find any solution for this. :(

Comment: What's the error you're receiving? Also, I kept most of your code the way you had it, but I would recommend just making the `url` parameter a static value (such as `url: '/loginHandling'`).